# Performance comparison of sort vs custom hash function for strings in Python

Tags: python, hash-function

I'm comparing the performance of sort vs a custom hash function for strings of varying length and the results are a bit surprising.  I expected the function prime_hash (and especially prime_hash2) in the following code to outperform sort_hash although the opposite is true.  Can anyone explain the perf difference?  Can anyone offer an alternate hash?  [The function should produce identical values for strings containing the same distribution of letters and different values for all other strings].

Here are the results I'm getting:

```
For strings of max length: 10
sort_hash: Time in seconds: 3.62555098534
prime_hash: Time in seconds: 5.5846118927
prime_hash2: Time in seconds: 4.14513611794
For strings of max length: 20
sort_hash: Time in seconds: 4.51260590553
prime_hash: Time in seconds: 8.87842392921
prime_hash2: Time in seconds: 5.74179887772
For strings of max length: 30
sort_hash: Time in seconds: 5.41446709633
prime_hash: Time in seconds: 11.4799649715
prime_hash2: Time in seconds: 7.58586287498
For strings of max length: 40
sort_hash: Time in seconds: 6.42467713356
prime_hash: Time in seconds: 14.397785902
prime_hash2: Time in seconds: 9.58741497993
For strings of max length: 50
sort_hash: Time in seconds: 7.25647807121
prime_hash: Time in seconds: 17.0482890606
prime_hash2: Time in seconds: 11.3653149605
```

And here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import time
import random
import string
from itertools import groupby

def prime(i, primes):
   for prime in primes:
      if not (i == prime or i % prime):
         return False
   primes.add(i)
   return i

def historic(n):
   primes = set([2])
   i, p = 2, 0
   while True:
      if prime(i, primes):
         p += 1
         if p == n:
            return primes
      i += 1

primes = list(historic(26))

def generate_strings(num, max_len):
   gen_string = lambda i: ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in xrange(i))
   return [gen_string(random.randrange(3, max_len)) for i in xrange(num)]

def sort_hash(s):
   return ''.join(sorted(s))

def prime_hash(s):
   return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [primes[ord(c) - ord('a')] for c in s])

def prime_hash2(s):
   res = 1
   for c in s:
      res = res * primes[ord(c) - ord('a')]
   return res

def dotime(func, inputs):
   start = time()
   groupby(sorted([func(s) for s in inputs]))
   print '%s: Time in seconds: %s' % (func.__name__, str(time() - start))

def dotimes(inputs):
   print 'For strings of max length: %s' % max([len(s) for s in inputs])
   dotime(sort_hash, inputs)
   dotime(prime_hash, inputs)
   dotime(prime_hash2, inputs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   dotimes(generate_strings(1000000, 11))
   dotimes(generate_strings(1000000, 21))
   dotimes(generate_strings(1000000, 31))
   dotimes(generate_strings(1000000, 41))
   dotimes(generate_strings(1000000, 51))
```

Comment: Yow. Someone else trying to outperform [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)...

Comment: No, not really.  I didn't want to use sort at all but rather just do a few arithmetical operations.  Substitute 'timsort' for 'sorted' above and my question still remains-- how to improve the perf of the arithmetic-based approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input from BoppreH, I was able to get a version of the arithmetic-based hash which outperforms even the C-implemented 'sorted'-based version:

```
primes = list(historic(26))
primes = {c : primes[ord(c) - ord('a')] for c in string.lowercase}

def prime_hash2(s):
   res = 1
   for c in s:
      res = res * primes[c]
   return res
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking why sort_hash (which is O(n*log n) ) is faster than the other functions that are O(n).

The reason is that your `n` is too small for `log(n)` to be significant.

Python's `sort()` is coded in C. If you coded your arithmetic functions in C, you would see the `n*log(n)` lose out for much smaller values of `n`

Aside: When you have lots of repeated items, timsort will be better than `n*log(n)`. Since there are only 256 characters, you will likely find that timsort approaches O(n) long before the strings are long enough to see the arithmetic versions get an advantage

Comment: Maybe so; but in each case there are still a number of operations to be performed: in the sort_hash case, moving elements around in-place. In the other cases: some arithmetic.  I expected the CPU to be better at arithmetic.  Nonetheless, I will try with a very large N.

Comment: @johanatan, Native math in Python is very slow (maybe 100 times slower than C). pypy should give you a closer result than CPython.

Comment: You were absolutely right about the `itertools.product`. I'm removing my incorrect answer as to not trick other people into the same mistake.

Comment: @BoppreH The lookup-table portion of your answer actually was helpful.  When applied to my original prime_hash2, it allowed it to outperform sort_hash (even on CPython). If you want to re-post just that portion of the answer, I will at least upvote it.